# Python cannot interprete special characters in path to HANA table (SQL)

Tags: python, sql, hana

I want to read a table stored in HANA directly from python. For that I use the following code:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi

import pandas as pd 

conn = dbapi.connect(
    address="address",
    port=XYZ,
    user="user",
    password="password"
)

print (conn.isconnected())

# Fetch table data 
stmnt = "select * from '_SYS_NAME'.'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name'"
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute(stmnt) 
result = cursor.fetchall() 
print('Create the dataframe')
```

The problem is in the line stmnt: I tried different ways of puting the path name so that python can read it as a string but none is working. I know the problem is not relying on the technique, because if the path is simple and not containing the special characters then the code works.

I tried all the following combinations (among others):

```
stmnt = "select * from '_SYS_NAME'.'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name'"
stmnt = """select * from '_SYS_NAME'.'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name'"""
stmnt = "select * from \'_SYS_NAME\'\.\'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name\'
stmnt = """select * from \'_SYS_NAME\'\.\'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name\'"""
```

The error I get is always the following:

```
hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "_SYS_NAME": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1)')
```

And the original path as I get it from SQL is:

```
'_SYS_NAME'.'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name'
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: I don't know HANA but I doubt the problem is on the Python side. What happens if you enter `select * from '_SYS_NAME'.'part1.part2.part3.part4.part5.part6/table_name'` in the HANA SQL console/interface?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the quotes? `stmnt = 'select * from "_SYS_BIC"."rwev.dev.bw.project.si.churn/SI_CV_CHU_7_DATA_MODEL"'`

Comment: @András, thanks a lot. That fixed the problem! Do you want to put your answer as a proper answer and then we mark the question as answered?

Comment: @jotNewie, yes, it is easier to find. And I need the reputation to avoid the annoying edit-limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse your quotes:

```
stmnt = 'select * from "_SYS_BIC"."rwev.dev.bw.project.si.churn/SI_CV_CHU_7_DATA_MODEL"'
```